# do you have any solution to reduce the build time?

Tags: silverlight, time, build

I'm working on a big Solution, which includes 20 projects(in silverlight, and use 10 wcf sevices), each tim to test presentation layer, I have to Build all Solution, and it take much more time.
do you  have the solution to reduce the build time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to Build/Configuration Manager... and uncheck the projects 
   that you are not working on. This way you only build the relevant
   project.
2. Create a solution which only include project that you wish to modify. Copy the DLLs from other projects into a folder. Go to Build, Your_Project Properties... Reference Path, and add that folder.
3. [Switch to parallel MSBuild](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HackParallelMSBuildsFromWithinTheVisualStudioIDE.aspx) (by adding external tool), which can utilize all your CPU cores. Set arguments to multiproc and verbosity - minimal:

   `/m /v:m`
4. Get rid of [unused styles](http://alsagile.com/post/19731792868/trim-your-build-on-silverlight-projects)
5. Use SSD
6. If you're on a laptop, make sure your machine is set in high performance mode.
7. Also refer to my [old blog post](http://www.redmountainsw.com/wordpress/1184/vs2010-slow-with-silverlight-speeding-up-tips/)

Comment: 0

down vote

favorite


 


When I tried to remove a dependency of a UI layer from ViewModel, I am getting this error message "The dependency was added by the project system and cannot be removed". What is the cause for this error? How I can solve this?

Comment: There are several StackOverflow posts regarding that problem. For the moment, you should just minimize the build set.